# No ethernet icon in Lion?

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar, ethernet

I remember having an ethernet icon in Tiger and Leopard in the menu bar. This was very convenient since it gave quick access to the settings just like you need it for airport:

[image]

In Lion I do not see this icon anymore. Also, I cannot find any way to activate it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are missing the Airport/Wi-Fi icon you can enable this in System Preferences -> Network:

[image]

For PPPoE services the same option is available once you added the service to the list of networks.

Comment: Yeah it works, but we were able to do this with the ethernet icon in the 10.6 and earlier. Because I mainly use the fast ethernet access, I've disabled the airport icon completely.

Comment: May this has been an icon from another utility app? MenuMeters maybe?

Comment: Nope. See this example: http://www.execulink.ca/files/8013/0566/0590/mac_leo-menu_bar-ethernet_connected.jpg

Comment: When I add a PPPoE service in the network preferences I get the option to add a menu icon as well (same as with Airport).

Comment: Yes. Did we not get this with ethernet aswell? Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Ok, apparently I was wrong. Sorry guys... (http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/917724)

Comment: No explanation was given on how to add the services for the original question asked and why do a screen shot of airport showing the option when the question asked related to the option not being there in the ethernet preferences.

Comment: Bert, did you read the text below the picture/screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer but still for those landing here looking for a Ethernet connectivity status icon in menu bar, check this macOS app [Ethernet Status - The Missing LAN Status Bar Icon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ethernet-status-missing-lan/id1186187538?ls=1&mt=12). It shows ethernet interface, IP Address and if interface is active via changing menu bar icon. More [here](https://www.vikramrao.in/apps/ethernetstatus)

[image]

*PS: I am the developer of the app*